# Assert string array member content

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

In this test, the required assertion is that if a member of the obtained string array has a value which is similar to something.

For example:
Say the obtained string array is

```
string[] obtainedArr = new string("c:\programfiles", "d:\morefiles", "e:\some");
```

Do we have something in the lines of:

```
Assert.That(obtainedArr, Has.Member.Which.Is.String.Containing("d:"), "D: location not obtained");
```

Or do we have a better way to achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Assert.True(obtainedArr.Any(s => s.Contains("d:")), "D: location not obtained");
```

Notes: by default string comparison is case-sensitive, so searching for `D:` will fail for your sample input. Also if you are looking for sub-path, then maybe `StartsWith` is more appropriate check, than `Contains`

```
Assert.That(obtainedArr.Any(s => 
   s.StartsWith("d:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Of course, this code is not very readable, so I would create (extension) method to check if given path is subpath of some other path.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Is that an extension method?
I am getting an error:
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any'

Comment: @dushyantp yes, `Any` is an extension method from `System.Linq` namespace. Just add appropriate using